# Within some points on a 2D-plane, find one point that is less than "P" away from each point.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, operations-research

If there are 10 given points on a 2d plane, how would one find a final point who's distance is less than P in distance away from each given point? Assuming such a final point exists, a final point that is less than P away from any given point. Is there an existing linear programming problem similar to this one might study?

Comment: Assume its coordinates to be $(x,y)$ and using the distance formula you’ll get 10 inequalities (circles). The region common to all 10 circles should be all the solutions.